# jQuery Slider that allows for <picture> element

Tags: html, image, css, picturefill

I have be trawling the web for a jQuery slider that allows for the `picture` element, but unable to find any, so I this is my final attempt before building my own custom slider.

Does anyone know of any jQuery sliders that allow for the `picture` element?

Comment: http://www.unheap.com/section/media/sliders-carousels/

Comment: some u have to buy some r free

Comment: i would imagine almost all of them would,  have you tried any jquery plugins?  Most of them just use a div and slide the div in and out and you can resize your <picture> element inside of that div with css maybe try Owl Carousel its free

Comment: have u tried the bootstrap carousal? or is that something diffrent?

Comment: here is one http://www.slidesjs.com/